# Set Paramerters in ScriptBlock when Executing Powershell Commands with C#

Tags: c#, powershell, scriptblock

I am trying to executing the following powershell command in C#

```
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {
  Get-MailboxPermission -Identity ${identity} -User ${user}
}
```

I tried with following C# code but couldn't set the identity and user parameters.

```
var command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", ScriptBlock.Create("Get-MailboxPermission -Identity ${identity} -User ${user}"));
command.AddParameter("identity", mailbox);
command.AddParameter("user", user);
```

When I hard code the values when creating the ScriptBlock, it's working fine. How can I set the params dynamically.

Is there a better way to do this rather concatenate values as below.

```
command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", ScriptBlock.Create("Get-MailboxPermission -Identity " + mailbox + " -User " + user));
```

Comment: `command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", ScriptBlock.Create("param(${identity}, ${user}) Get-MailboxPermission -Identity ${identity} -User ${user}"));
command.AddParameter("ArgumentList", new object[]{mailbox, user});`

Comment: Thanks @PetSerAl Exactly I was looking for. Why don't you post this as an answer? May help who is looking for a same solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem with your C# code is that you pass `identity` and `user` as parameters for `Invoke-Command`. It more or less equivalent to the following PowerShell code:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    Get-MailboxPermission -Identity ${identity} -User ${user}
} -identity $mailbox -user $user
```

And since `Invoke-Command` does not have `identity` and `user` parameters, it will fail, when you run it. To pass values to the remote session, you need to pass them to `-ArgumentList` parameter. To use passed values, you can declare them in `ScriptBlock`'s `param` block, or you can use `$args` automatic variable. So, actually you need equivalent of following PowerShell code:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {
    param(${identity}, ${user})
    Get-MailboxPermission -Identity ${identity} -User ${user}
} -ArgumentList $mailbox, $user
```

In C# it would be like this:

```
var command = new PSCommand();
command.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
command.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", ScriptBlock.Create(@"
    param(${identity}, ${user})
    Get-MailboxPermission -Identity ${identity} -User ${user}
"));
command.AddParameter("ArgumentList", new object[]{mailbox, user});
```